# Replace a nth character using regex in Java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to learn regex in Java.
So far, I've been trying some little mini challenges and I'm wondering if there is a way to define a nth character.
For instance, let's say I have this string: todayiwasnotagoodday
If I want to replace the third (fourth or seventh) character, how I can define a regex in order to change an specific "index", for this example the 'd' for an empty space "".
I've been searching about it, but so far my implementations match from the first element to the third: ^[a-z]{3}
¿Is it possible to define this regex?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the third character with a space via regex, you could try a regex replace all:

```java
String input = "todayiwasnotagoodday";
String output = input.replaceAll("^(.{2}).(.*)$", "$1 $2");
System.out.println(output); // to ayiwasnotagoodday
```

Note that you could also avoid regex here, and just use substring operations:

```
String output = input.substring(0, 2) + " " + input.substring(3);
System.out.println(output); // to ayiwasnotagoodday
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now I have more experience about groups in regex. Definitely, this will help me a lot in future implementations.